# In HqlNamedParams if where condition does not yield result fetch all rows

Tags: hql

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("from country ");
query.append("and stateId in (:stateId)");
hqlNamedParam.addParamAndValue("stateId", values);
```

Here if "values" doesn't exist in table, fetch all rows.

How do I do it?

Comment: OP, could you please elaborate on this _"if "values" doesnt exist in table, fetch all rows"_ What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: @bpgergo here i have to do best match if values are there ill consider them other wise i have to live with whatever i have!! please write the syntax i going wrong there!!

Comment: @Raghu Chandra: hi, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I've misunderstood the question, now I edit my answer:

You must run two queries.

```
// The first:

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("from country ");
query.append("and stateId in (:stateId)");
hqlNamedParam.addParamAndValue("stateId", values);

// The second (only if the first doesn't return rows)

if (outList == null || outList.size == 0) {
    StringBuilder query2 = new StringBuilder("from country ");
}
```

Alternatively (but you use more subqueries with count)

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("from country ");
query.append(" where 
    (select count(c2.id) from country c2 where c2.stateid in (:stateId)) > 0
    and cs.stateid in (:stateId)
    or (select count(c3.id) from country c3 where c3.stateid in (:stateId)) = 0");
hqlNamedParam.addParamAndValue("stateId", values);
```

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood OP. It says "if "values" doesnt exist in table, fetch all rows". Which I interpret as something like "if the original query does not return anything, because the given stateid does not appear in the country table, then run t the query again, without the stateid where clause"

Comment: Thanks for the reply here my concern is i should still go and search database if they are not there in the database i have to consider all other.

Comment: @bpgergo: Mmm yes, I misunderstood OP. Now I try to canghe my answer. Thanks